# Python TCP Client/Server To Serial

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, serial-port

This is my first attempt at the Python language. I'm trying to create a TCP client connection to a server, but have the connection fall back into a server mode if the client connection fails after a certain number of attempts. While in server mode it would be able to attempt to return back to client mode if it receives a command to do so or if a certain period of time has passed (reconnect timer of some sort). While in client or server mode all regular communication from the external server will be passed out a serial interface /dev/ttyUSB0 and vice-versa (client mode only). The communication will have to be examined in both directions so that other processes can be queued off of particular commands that pass through, which may include dropping the original message from passing out the serial or TCP port. There will also be a secondary serial interface to send commands to a connected cellular modem. I'm assuming this would have to be achieved with some sort of threading approach to be able to monitor the serial and network connections concurrently, but I'm not familiar enough with Python to know how it works.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
import socket
import thread
import time
import string
import serial
import serial.threaded

#######################################
#global variable
connected = 0 #holds the connection status, 0 : disconnected , 1 : connected
HBCounter = 0 #a counter that is related to heartbeat sent from server
HBSend = 0 #controls the flow of hearbeat sent by client
soc = socket.socket()#client socket
#######################################
class SerialPort(serial.threaded.Protocol):
    """serial->socket"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = None

    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def data_received(self, data):
        if self.socket is not None:
            self.socket.sendall(data)
#######################################
#this function tries to connect to the server
def tcpConnect():
    global connected, soc
    connected = 0
    s = socket.socket()          #socket object
    host = x.x.x.x
    port = 51015  # The server port
    try:
        s.connect((host, port)) #connecting to server
    except:
        tcpConnect() #retry on failure
    connected = 1
    soc = s
    thread.start_new_thread(tcpReadLine,(s,parse)) #read thread
#######################################
#timer class, needs user defined callback function(cb)
class timer:
    def __init__(self,timeout,func):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.func = func
    def start(self):
        go = 1
        curTime = time.time()
        while go:
            _time = time.time()
            if _time - curTime >= self.timeout:
                go = 0
        self.timerTimeout()
    def run(self):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.start,())
    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.func()
        self.run()
#######################################
#reads tcp socket, will call cb function when a whole line is detected
def tcpReadLine(tempSoc,func):
    lock = checkConnection()
    while lock == 0:
        lock = checkConnection()#checks if we are connected
    print ("connected")
    str = ""
    while lock:
        try:
            str += tempSoc.recv(1)
        except:
            lock = checkConnection()  
        if string.find(str,"\r\n") != -1 :
          func(str)
          str = ""
          lock = checkConnection()
#######################################
#parses the incoming data, for now we only print it, tcpRead line callback function
def parse(data):
    global HBCounter
    HBCounter = 0;  #we recently recieved data so connection is alive
    ser.write(data)
#######################################
#timer callback function
def CBTimeout():
    global HBSend, HBCounter, connected
    HBSend = HBSend + 1
    HBCounter = HBCounter + 1
    if  HBCounter >= 3 : # 3*timeout value inactivity from server, reset connection
        soc.close()
        thread.start_new_thread(tcpConnect,()) #starts a thread to manage connection
        HBCounter = 0
    if HBSend >= 2: # 2*timeout value inactivity from us, sending heartbeat
        tcpSend("HB\r\n")
#######################################
#sending routine
def tcpSend(data):
    global HBSend
    lock = checkConnection()
    while lock == 0:
        lock = checkConnection()#checks if we are connected
    try:
        soc.send(data)
        HBSend = 0 #recently sent data
    except:
        print "write failure"
#######################################
def checkConnection():
    return connected
#######################################
#######################################
#main program starts here
ser = serial.serial_for_url('/dev/ttyUSB0', do_not_open=True) #connect to serial port of Meshnet board
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.rtscts = False
ser.xonxoff = False

serModem = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200,timeout=1) #connect to USB Modem

try:
    ser.open()
    serModem.open()
except serial.SerialException as e:
    sys.stderr.write('Could not open serial port {}: {}\n'.format(ser.name, e))
    sys.exit(1)

dataSerial = SerialPort()
serial_worker = serial.threaded.ReaderThread(ser, dataSerial)
modemSerial = SerialPort()
modem_serial_worker = serial.threaded.ReaderThread(serModem, modemSerial)
serial_worker.start()
modem_serial_worker.start()
thread.start_new_thread(tcpConnect,()) #starts a thread to manage connection  
timer1 = timer(10,CBTimeout) #create a new timer with 10 sec timeout
timer1.run() #run timer
```